# ‘Or...’ at the end of a question

Tags: conjunctions, questions

Recently I have noticed that, in a casual conversation, I tend to end a lot of alternative type questions with ‘or’ followed by a short pause, during which I would wait the other people to response with an answer. Probably because I don’t know what to say for the other alternatives and expect the other person to fill the gap. To clarify with two examples:

> A: Are you conducting these surveys for your doctorate degree? Or ...
>   B: Oh no, it’s just a pastime.

---

> A: Now that we are here, which one do you want to try first? The slide, roller coaster or...
>   B: Let’s go on the Ferris wheel.

Do native speakers do this? Or do I need something after ‘or’, like ‘what/something’ for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a native speaker but to me it sounds perfectly fine and idiomatically acceptable to end a question with a prompting "or?"

Comment: This native speaker concurs.

Answer (score 0):

this native speaker says it is a lazy habit.
The purpose of using 'or' is to provide two or more options, not one. otherwise it is not a choice, which 'or' proposes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).